# C# Datagridview Binding to a Class not updating

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview, inotifypropertychanged

I have a datagridview that I am binding to a class. I add to the class but the datagridview is not updating.

My bind:

```
  ScannedChecks = new ScannedChecks();
  ScannedChecks.AddCheck(DateTime.Now, "22222", "checknumdd", "routingdd", _checkData, 4);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ScannedChecks;
```

I went ahead and did the AddCheck to see if it was reaching the datagridview and it isn't... The class is being updated though.

My class:

```
namespace SSS.Ckentry
{
  public class ScannedChecks  : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ScannedChecks()
    {
      ScannedChecksCollection = new ObservableCollection<ScannedCheck>();
    }

    public void AddCheck(DateTime checkDate, string accountNumber, string checkNumber, string bankRoutingNumber, string bankAccountNumber, decimal checkAmount)
    {
      var scc = new ScannedCheck
                  {
                    CheckDate = checkDate,
                    AccountNumber = accountNumber,
                    CheckNumber = checkNumber,
                    BankRoutingNumber = bankRoutingNumber,
                    BankAccountNumber = bankAccountNumber,
                    CheckAmount = checkAmount,
                  };

      ScannedChecksCollection.Add(scc);

    }

    public ObservableCollection<ScannedCheck> ScannedChecksCollection { get; set; }

    public class ScannedCheck
    {
      public DateTime CheckDate { get; set; }
      public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
      public string CheckNumber { get; set; }
      public string BankRoutingNumber { get; set; }
      public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
      public decimal CheckAmount { get; set; }
    }


  }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever replace the ScannedChecksCollection  with a new ScannedChecksCollection, the property setter should fire the PropertyChanged exent.

```
    private ObservableCollection<ScannedCheck> scannedChecksCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<ScannedCheck> ScannedChecksCollection {
        get
        {
            return scannedChecksCollection; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != scannedChecksCollection)
            {
                value = scannedChecksCollection;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ScannedChecksCollection");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
```

If checks are modifiable,  ScannedCheck should implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Similarly, he'll need to notify prop change on his properties of his object instead of having the shortcut get / set.

Comment: And... instead of AddCheck(...) his he could just ScannedChecks.Add(New ScannedCheck() { CheckDate = .... });

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ScannedChecks.ScannedChecksCollection;
```