# How to update my gridView.ItemsSource in C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a problem with a `GridView` and the `ItemsSource`

My Code looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyData = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
...
gridView.ItemsSource = MyData;
```

when I add something to `MyData` I instantly see it in the grid. But when I edit a element of the type `MyClass` in `MyData` I dont see the changes in the grid.

How to refresh the grid so I also see the changes made on on `MyClass` item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` item must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), that is `MyClass` in your case.

look here

[How do I use INotifyPropertyChanged in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532285/how-do-i-use-inotifypropertychanged-in-winrt)

Answer (score -2):

One option is to notify the data grid by notifying the changes. Similar like the following 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529829/c-sharp-datagridview-binding-to-a-class-not-updating)

Comment: There is no refresh method!

Comment: The other option could be notifying when the item source changed. 
Fore example like this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529829/c-sharp-datagridview-binding-to-a-class-not-updating